# Using TEventLog in lazarus

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I understand that EventLog is capable into writing the exception messages into a log on disk.I have managed to setup the component, but when I set the component to active and do a simple test like:

```
eventlog.Debug('Application has started!');
```

I receive the following exception :

Operation not allowed when eventlog is active.

What am I doing wrong ? I can't find the exception in the log what so ever eaven if I set RaiseExceptionOnError to true.

Please a simple sample usage would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal working sample: A Form with two buttons and one eventlog.

Code (change $Username):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EventLog1.LogType := ltFile;
  EventLog1.FileName := 'C:\users\$USERNAME\Desktop\Test.log';
  EventLog1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EventLog1.Debug('This is a test.');
end;
```

Click first on Button1, then on Button2. Have fun.

Comment: how can i catch all exceptions in the event log? I have generated an exception but It's not written to the log shouldn't this process be automatically ?

Comment: I've setup a exception handler and I manually write the exception into the log, but I tought this functionality is already built in.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to auto-log exceptions, have a look at http://wiki.freepascal.org/Logging_exceptions#Handling_exceptions